# sending email through php not working

Tags: php, email, html-email

I have a piece of code that will not work i don't understand why, i am trying to get the information sent to the database and also sent to the email address, it is saving it to the database but will not send to the email, even though it echoes your email was successfully sent. Any help appreciated.

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $to = "edonaghy--@hotmail.co.uk"; 
  $subject = "Dress fitting"; 
  $time = $_REQUEST['time']; 
  $date = $_REQUEST['date']; 
  $headers = "From: $email"; 
  $sent = mail($to, $date, $headers); 
  if($sent) 
  {
    print "Your mail was sent successfully";
  }
  else 
  {
    print "We encountered an error sending your mail";
  }

  mysql_select_db("lr", $con);

  mail("edonaghy--@hotmail.co.uk", $time, $date, $place, $comments);
  $sql="INSERT INTO fitting (time, date, place, comments) VALUES ('$_POST[time]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[place]','$_POST[comments]')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo "Information has been sent!"; 
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't sent ? I mean it could fail on many places : blocked by SMTP server, blocked by destination server, filtered as SPAM. For example, sending an email "on behalf of" (= forcing the "from" email from a domain you don't own) is a very common exclusion problem.

Comment: you are using mail() differently in both places. in the first you are sending the headers as the body. in the second you are sending $place as the headers, though that is undefined at this point in the example you gave. So are $comments and presumably $time and $date depending on the $_REQUEST vars. have you read the mail manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: The obvious first question that comes to my mind, is are you using this on `localhost`?

Comment: It's probably not sending because he's not using `mail()` correct. Let's get him using it correctly, then ask questions.

Comment: yes i am on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it wont send your e-mail if your localhost werent properly configured, so I suggest you to test on your server if you have one.

There are libraries that can help you with a better code like [php-simple-mail](https://github.com/eoghanobrien/php-simple-mail)
Example:

```
require 'class.simple_mail.php';
$mailer = new SimpleMail();

$time = $_REQUEST['time'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$message = "<strong>My message on date:".$date." ".$time."</strong>";



$send   = $mailer->setTo('edonaghy--@hotmail.co.uk', 'Your Email')
                 ->setSubject('Test Message')
                 ->setFrom('no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
                 ->addMailHeader('Reply-To', 'no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
                 ->addMailHeader('Cc', 'bill@example.com', 'Bill Gates')
                 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
                 ->setMessage($message)
                 ->setWrap(100)
                 ->send();
echo ($send) ? 'Email sent successfully' : 'Could not send email';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using mail wrong.

It's meant to be used like this:

```
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)
```

So yours would be:

```
$to = "email@hotmail.co.uk"; 
$subject = "Dress fitting"; 
$headers = "From: email@hotmail.co.uk";

$message = "Time:".$_REQUEST['time']."\r\n";
$message .= "Date:".$_REQUEST['date']."\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

This is assuming your `$_REQUEST`'s are working.

Your second `mail()` is using variables that you haven't even set yet (`$comments`, `$place`) etc.

Set them first:

```
$place = $_POST['place'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
```